# <a4j:jsFunction> calling returns undefined from server

Tags: ajax, richfaces, jsf-1.2

In my Managed Bean, I have a simple boolean method:

```
public class UploadBean {

    // ...

    public boolean getPossuiNotasFiscaisNaoTransmitidas() {
        boolean result = false;

        // Some computation ...

        return result;
    }

}
```

In my XHTML page, I am using RichFaces 3.3.3 tabPanel. In a specific tab I need make a confirmation to see if I really open it or not:

```
    <a4j:jsFunction name="possuiNotasFiscaisNaoTransmitidas" action="#{uploadBean.getPossuiNotasFiscaisNaoTransmitidas}" immediate="true" process="tab-10" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="tab-10"/>
    <a4j:loadScript src="../../js/orcamentoVistoria.js"/>
    <rich:tabPanel id="abas" switchType="ajax" >
        <!-- many tabs... -->
        <rich:tab 
                id="tab-10" 
                name="tab-10" 
                ontabenter="return prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais();"
                ontableave="return prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais();" >
            <!-- content -->
        </rich:tab>
    </rich:tabPanel>
```

The function `prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais()` in `orcamentoVistoria.js` calls the managed bean method:

```
function prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais() {
    console.info("prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais: Entrando");                                // LOG 1
    var serverResponse = possuiNotasFiscaisNaoTransmitidas();
    console.info("prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais: serverResponse? " + serverResponse);       // LOG 2
    var result = serverResponse ? confirm("Proceed?"): true;
    console.info("prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais: Resultado? " + result);                    // LOG 3
    return result;
}
```

**What I expected**: when I enter (or leave) in the tab, the page will call the managed bean method. If its answer was true, it will be asked to the user if she wants to continue to enter/leave. If its answer was false, so the tab will be directly entered/left.

**What I really got**: when I enter (or leave) in the tab, the page *apparently* calls the managed bean method. At least, in debug, I can see the method being executed (many times, actually). However, in the JS return (`LOG 2` line), the `serverResponse` variable is undefined. It is like the page was not waiting for the server response. Consequently the JS function will always return `true` and the tab always will be directly entered/left.

So, What should I do? Is it some specific attribute in `<a4j:jsFunction>` tag?

Thanks

Rafael Afonso

**UPDATE 17/02/2016**

@Makhiel, thanks for your suggestion. However, what I need is that by some way, after the execution of `oncomplete`, allow or not the tab change. But (at least from I could understand), it is possible only through `ontabenter` or `ontableave` from tab.

Following the Makhiel suggestion, I did the following suggestions in my code:

Managed Bean

```
public class UploadBean {

    private boolean questionarAbaNotasFiscais = false;

    // ...

    public boolean getPossuiNotasFiscaisNaoTransmitidas() {
        this.questionarAbaNotasFiscais = false;

        // Some computation. It can change questionarAbaNotasFiscais or not ...

        return this.questionarAbaNotasFiscais;
    }

    // ...

    public boolean isQuestionarAbaNotasFiscais() {
        return questionarAbaNotasFiscais;
    }
}
```

XHTML:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="possuiNotasFiscaisNaoTransmitidas" action="#{uploadBean.getPossuiNotasFiscaisNaoTransmitidas}"
    data="#{uploadBean.questionarAbaNotasFiscais}" oncomplete="questionarAbaNotasFiscais = data; console.timeEnd('consulta');console.info('servidor retornou ' + questionarAbaNotasFiscais)"
    immediate="true" process="tab-10" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="tab-10"/>
<a4j:loadScript src="../../js/orcamentoVistoria.js"/>
<rich:tabPanel id="abas" switchType="ajax" >
    <!-- many tabs... -->
    <rich:tab 
            id="tab-10" 
            name="tab-10" 
            ontabenter="return prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais();"
            ontableave="return prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais();" >
        <!-- content -->
    </rich:tab>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

Java Script

```
var questionarAbaNotasFiscais = null;

function prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais() {
//  questionarAbaNotasFiscais = null;
    console.info("prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais: Entrando");
    console.time("consulta");
    var b = possuiNotasFiscaisNaoTransmitidas();

    console.info("prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais: Esperando retorno. b = " + b);
    console.time("watingReturn")
    while(typeof questionarAbaNotasFiscais === null) {
        // wait for return
    }
    console.timeEnd("watingReturn")
    console.info("prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais: respostaServidor? " + questionarAbaNotasFiscais);
    var result = questionarAbaNotasFiscais ? confirm(msgNotasNaoTransmitidas): true;
    console.info("prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais: Resultado? " + result);

    questionarAbaNotasFiscais = null;
    return result;
}
```

**What I want**: `prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais()` function calls `possuiNotasFiscaisNaoTransmitidas()` and wait until the global variable `questionarAbaNotasFiscais` is filled in `oncomplete` and proceed as waited. Once that in this declaration and at the end of `prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais()` function `questionarAbaNotasFiscais` is always setted to `null`, It is waited that always execute the loop above, finishing only when `oncomplete` be executed.

**What I got**: When `prosseguirAbaNotasFiscais()` is executed, calls the server function, but apparently is not waiting by server return. I observed that first the JS function is called, the page is reloaded and just then the server function is called.

Ok, the server function is executed async. So Is there some way to force to wait until the server function?

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Comment: You can test it with `switchType="client"`. You can call bean method in attribute like `ontableave="if (#{bean.method} &amp;&amp; !confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed?')) return false;"`

Comment: @VasilLukach it doesn't work like that, the EL expression would be evaluated when the page is rendered, not when the "tableave" event fires

Comment: @Makhiel, this crazy construction really works in real JSF 1.2 application in commandButton attributes. I never tested it in tabPanel. It was only suggestion.

Comment: @VasilLukach there are some attributes that are only evaluated during the request processing but if it worked like that you wouldn't need a commandButton, you'd just write `<button onclick="#{bean.method}" />`

Comment: Instead of describing how you want the function to work can you describe what you're trying to do? Prevent the user from switching to another tab? Do you need to go to the server for that?

Comment: @Makhiel, Let´s go: When I am in any tab and want to enter in the special tab I should ask the server (using the function defined in `a4j:jsFunction`) to see if I should make a question to the user. If I receive a false, I enter directly. If I receive a true the page shows a dialog with a warning and asking if I want to continue. Answering "yes", I enter in the tab. Otherwise, I continue in the original tab. The equivalent should happen when I want to go from the special tab to another tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
var serverResponse = possuiNotasFiscaisNaoTransmitidas();
```

This will not work, a JavaScript method cannot directly execute a method on the server and give you back the result. What `a4j:jsFunction` does is send an AJAX request to the server and then the server sends back a response. It is asynchronous so yes the page is not waiting on the server (it would be bad if it did).

Instead of the returning a result from the bean method you save the result to a bean property, then you use @data:

```
<a4j:jsFunction data="#{bean.result}"
    name="possuiNotasFiscaisNaoTransmitidas" 
    oncomplete="if (data) {doSomething();}"
    … />
```

The "oncomplete" code will execute when the response comes back from the server.

I am not sure if the result value will be directly in the `data` variable, better check with `console.log`.